# What is the relation between multiple-regression and pearson's r?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, pearson-r

What is the relation between these two, not $r^2$, but Pearson's $r$ and multiple $r$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multiple correlation coefficient (usually represented $R$) is Pearson's correlation coefficient $r$ between the predicted values and the observed values.  Multiple regression finds a many to one mapping that turns the multidimensional set of $X$ variables into a unidimensional variate $\hat y$.  Thus, you can correlate it with $y$ normally.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! And Why can we not add up Pearsons R and calculate R2???

Comment: I don't follow that, @ivanskidobrovski. You can calculate the multiple $R^2$ from the multiple $R$, simply by squaring it. By the way, if this resolved your issue, you can accept it by clicking the check mark to its left below the vote total.

Comment: But adding Pearsons r will turn out wrong - adding 2 Pearson's r will it give the same at squaring them?

Comment: it si not the multiple r.... it is pearson's r and r2 -

Comment: Why can't we add all Pearson's r and calculate R2 based on this sum?

Comment: I am not really understanding your line of thinking. You can't add the univariate correlations between different $x$'s & $y$ and get the multiple $R$ or the multiple $R^2$.