# Why can't we add all the individual Pearson's $r$'s in a multiple regression and calculate $R^2$ based on this sum?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, r-squared, pearson-r

Why can't we add all the individual Pearson's $r$'s in a multiple regression and calculate $R^2$ based on this sum? Is there an easy mathematical explanation to this as $r^2$ is squared and don't add up some way?

Comment: When there are just two variables and $r$ is negative, you have no hope of creating a *nonnegative* $R^2$ from its sum, do you?  Instead of inventing a formula and asking why it doesn't work, why not study the theory and the formulas that *do* work?  That is a much faster and surer way towards understanding.

Comment: What is $R^2$ intended to measure? What would be the purpose of adding the correlations? What would it measure?

Comment: You're asking the same question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122109/what-is-the-relation-between-multiple-regression-and-pearsons-r Please don't duplicate questions.

Comment: I don't see this as the same question, @NickCox. It is an extension / follow-on question though.

Comment: My point is that we don't need this question too. By all the other question can edited or extended.

Comment: ok - but thanks to Gung for swift answer

Comment: I tried to edit your Q for greater clarity, Ivanski. I had to guess what the 2nd sentence was getting at, though. Please ensure I got it (more or less) right.

Comment: @NickCox, although English isn't the OP's native language, I think these are separate, clear, intuitive, & self-contained questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know how to answer this.  I guess I would just say that you can't add up the univariate Pearson's $r$'s and get $R$ or $R^2$.  Bear in mind that $r$ is bound by $[-1,\ 1]$, and that $R^2$ is bound by $[0,\ 1]$.  So it may be easy to see that simple addition would yield sums that violate those rules.  Here is an example you can play with yourself:

```r
## here are 3 simple variables x1, x2, & y:
x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
x2 = c(2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,12,11,14,13,16,15,18,17,20,19)
y  = c(3,1,2,6,4,5,9,7,8,12,10,11,15,13,14,18,16,17,20,19)

## here are their Pearson's correlations:
cor(x1,y)                 # r = 0.9714286
cor(x2,y)                 # r = 0.9593985
cor(x1,x2)                # r = 0.9849624

## here I fit a multiple regression model & get R, & R^2:
model = lm(y~x1+x2)
cor(y, fitted(model))     # R   = 0.9715432
summary(model)$r.squared  # R^2 = 0.9438961

## we can square R to get R^2:  
0.9715432^2               # = 0.9438962

## adding r(x1,y) + r(x2,y) does not equal either R or R^2, though:
0.9714286 + 0.9593985     # = 1.930827
```

Comment: great great great - I got it!